# Placing an ASSERT in a SQL Server query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

As part of a `MERGE` query that I want to run I'd like to assert at runtime that a certain condition holds. When a `MERGE`-match is found I'd like to update a certain column and have the following logic executed:

1. If the target column is `NULL`, write the source value
2. If the target is `NOT NULL`, assert that target and source are identical

I expect that the two values are always identical in case 2 but I might have made a mistake (have a bug). When that happens I'd like to crash the statement and let my app report the error. This is a very rare error condition, not something that can happen as part of usual processing.

So I was thinking that I could abuse a **divide-by-zero** exception to trigger a crash:

```
MERGE
...
WHEN MATCHED BY TARGET THEN UPDATE SET
  TargetCol = CASE
    WHEN TargetCol IS NULL THEN SourceCol
    WHEN TargetCol = SourceCol THEN SourceCol
    ELSE 0/0 END --crash!
```

Will this work reliably? Is there a reason this should not be done?

Comment: I think `RAISEERROR` could be a good choice if you want to assert within a query.

Comment: @BinayaRegmi can't call it as part of a query.

Comment: Why don't you want to use it in a block?

Comment: @BinayaRegmi because it's inconvenient. I'd need to funnel the invalid data out of the MERGE into a temp variable and then analyze that. Also, the MERGE would be done by then and all writes would have happened.

Comment: Have you tried putting a `CHECK` constraint on the target `OUTPUT` table? That should blow up the statement.

Comment: @JonSeigel the predicate is a function of both src and target. When the two do not match => error.

Comment: LOL my plan failed. `Msg 333, Level 16, State 1, Line 21
The target table '@check' of the OUTPUT INTO clause cannot have any enabled check constraints or any enabled rules. Found check constraint or rule 'CK__#60A75C0F__619B8048'.` Good to know.

Comment: @JonSeigel oh now I understand what you meant. Nice idea :) Be careful, you might find another `MERGE` bug!

Comment: That's not a bug -- clearly it's by design -- I just wasn't aware of that restriction. Oh well.

Comment: @JonSeigel I was referring to the dozen of merge bugs already found: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/ There are nasty corruption issues among them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Will this work reliably?*

The answer to this depends on the strength of the guarantee you need. There have been bugs in the past around `CASE` evaluation-order, for example [constant-folding an error-generating expression](http://bartduncansql.wordpress.com/2011/03/03/dont-depend-on-expression-short-circuiting-in-t-sql-not-even-with-case). There are no current bugs in SQL Server 2014 that I am aware of that would affect your query, but that does not mean they might not occur in future.

This is a risk with any code of course, but my assessment is that the risk is higher when combining this technique with `MERGE`. Merge has a complex implementation, and there have been [many related bugs](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement) in the past, as you know.

> *Is there a reason this should not be done?*

Personally, I would look to avoid a divide-by-zero as part of the solution. A better option might be to attempt to write a value that violates an explicit `CHECK` (or some other) constraint on the target table. This would result in an explicit Assert operator in the execution plan, positioned after the Merge operator. It might not be *desirable* to add such a constraint (or even possible if the column is allowed to hold all values in its type domain) but it is one thing to consider.

One other general suggestion: avoid updating the target column when the values match. This is logically a no-op, but that doesn't always translate physically.

```
DECLARE @target AS TABLE (pk integer PRIMARY KEY, col2 integer NULL CHECK (col2 <> -1));
DECLARE @source AS TABLE (pk integer PRIMARY KEY, col2 integer NULL);

INSERT @target VALUES (1, 100), (2, NULL), (3, 300);
INSERT @source VALUES (1, 100), (2, 200), (3, 301);

MERGE @target AS T
USING @source AS S
    ON S.pk = T.pk
WHEN MATCHED 
    AND
    (
        -- No update if values match
        T.col2 IS NULL 
        OR T.col2 <> S.col2
    )
    THEN UPDATE SET col2 = 
        CASE 
            WHEN T.col2 IS NULL THEN S.col2
            ELSE -1 -- violates CHECK constraint
        END;
```

[image: Merge plan with Assert]

Comment: The nice thing about the CHECK tactic is that it is guaranteed to work. I'll take away this idea for future development. At the moment I'm more interested in having an extremely lightweight way to assert something (lightweight from a development standpoint). Reading your analysis I think the division trick is OK for non-critical functionality that does not kill people when it fails.